# Angular: Fixed Top Menu, switching page but not scrolling top

Tags: angularjs

I have a fixed top menu in Angular but when I try to switch page (within the app) the browser windows is not scrolling up.

I try to do this in my controller (this code is loaded every time i switch page within the app):

```
$('body').scroll();
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100);
```

None of which is working.

Is there any trick that i am missing?

I tried this as well:

```
$location.hash('#top');
// call $anchorScroll()
$anchorScroll();
```

but without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should never attach DOM events or modify DOM from controller. You can use directives for that.

As per you question - AngularJS has an event called '$routeChangeSuccess'. 
You can attach handler to this event with `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {...})` and run scrolling code inside.

Comment: Hey Thanks Patryk, I know but i am just trying everything out there to see what is working, I try your code and the listener is triggered but still it's not going up, with jQuery / window / or anchorScroll

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: k your fix worked, i had another JavaScript code that's was causing the problem (of your fix not working) ;) Thank you!